# Is there a way to get the follower list of an instagram account?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I noticed instagram changed their API but I would like to clean up my followers (I noticed some of them are bots and that just looks bad).

I would like to get a list of the usernames so I can determine if I want to block them or not (manually, because of API changes).

Is there any way that I could download that information?

I've tried different websites but they either don't work anymore, ask for money (and probably wouldn't work) or they just vanished.

I've also tried some python scripts with instaloader and they all retreive nothing, as in they login just fine, but can't show me any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way using javascript and Instagram's unofficial API.

Here are two functions I have written:

The first is *random_wait_time* to wait between the requests,
the second one *get_followers* makes the actual requests.

```js
const random_wait_time = (waitTime = 300) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return resolve();
  }, Math.random() * waitTime);
});


const get_followers = async(userId, userFollowerCount) => {
  let userFollowers = [],
    batchCount = 20,
    actuallyFetched = 20,
    url = `https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=c76146de99bb02f6415203be841dd25a&variables={"id":"${userId}","include_reel":true,"fetch_mutual":true,"first":"${batchCount}"}`;
  while (userFollowerCount > 0) {
    const followersResponse = await fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        const nodeIds = [];
        for (const node of res.data.user.edge_followed_by.edges) {
          nodeIds.push(node.node.id);
        }
        actuallyFetched = nodeIds.length;
        return {
          edges: nodeIds,
          endCursor: res.data.user.edge_followed_by.page_info.end_cursor
        };
      }).catch(err => {
        userFollowerCount = -1;
        return {
          edges: []
        };
      });
    await random_wait_time();
    userFollowers = [...userFollowers, ...followersResponse.edges];
    userFollowerCount -= actuallyFetched;
    url = `https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=c76146de99bb02f6415203be841dd25a&variables={"id":"${userId}","include_reel":true,"fetch_mutual":true,"first":${batchCount},"after":"${followersResponse.endCursor}"}`;
  }
  console.log(userFollowers);
  return userFollowers;
};
```

Now open the developer console of your browser with `F12`on *Windows* or `Cmd + Alt + j` on *Mac* and paste the code from above.

Then proceed to call *get_followers* with your **user_id** and **followers_count** or an upper limit:

`get_followers(493525227, 10)`

and copy the result **user_id** of your followers.

If you want all the data for the followers then change the returned object:

`return {
     edges: res.data.user.edge_followed_by.edges,
     endCursor: res.data.user.edge_followed_by.page_info.end_cursor
 };`

P.S
To get your **user_id** you can use [that service](https://codeofaninja.com/tools/find-instagram-user-id) or the value of the cookie **ds_user_id** in the [developer console](https://www.wikihow.com/View-Cookies).

The reason to paste the code in the console is that each request automatically passes all the available cookies on the domain. Doing so not from *instagram.com* requires you to supply all the cookies manually.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for this! I tried the code you posted and it works great, but then I tried your suggestion in changing the returned object and it gives off an error:

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: res is not defined
    at get_followers (<anonymous>:41:13)

It also blocked a cross-origin response, so it might be because of that but I'm not sure.

.js:62 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://graph.instagram.com/logging_client_events with MIME type application/json. 

Thank you anyways, really helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You can change the *return* object inside the while loop(right under  *actuallyFetched = nodeIds.length;*) to the full version. Do not change *return userFollowers;*. Hope it helps !

Comment: Ohhhhh sorry, that absolutely makes more sense. Feel kind of dumb now haha, thank you so much! Just tried it **the right way** and it is amazing!

Comment: Glad I could help! I am currently building a chrome extension for Instagram automation, but it still lacks a lot of stuff. You can check it here: https://github.com/valiok98/Instahelper. If you need anything else about Instagram, don't hesitate to write an email. Thx

Answer (score -2):

You're better off using a tool such as Keygram ~ https://www.thekeygram.com

It will handle what you are trying to do with instagram followers automatically

It's a cross platform desktop app compatible with both Mac and Windows